SQL Scan vs Seek when using OR in where criteria
Consider the following two queries from the AdventureWorks database. The where criteria is entirely on indexed columns. If you use OR criteria both tables get a full table scan on them. In the second scenario the criteria is split out over two queries that are unioned. In the second scenario both tables get index seeks. Can someone explain why SQL can't/won't optimize the first query to do an index seek?  Are there ways to tell SQL to do a seek without rewriting as a UNION? (I've tried index hints with no success)
SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks2022].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] hdr
JOIN [AdventureWorks2022].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] dtl ON hdr.SalesOrderID = dtl.SalesOrderID
WHERE hdr.SalesOrderID = 43659 OR dtl.SalesOrderDetailID =  43659

----

SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks2022].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] hdr
JOIN [AdventureWorks2022].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] dtl ON hdr.SalesOrderID = dtl.SalesOrderID
WHERE hdr.SalesOrderID = 43659
 
UNION
 
SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks2022].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] hdr
JOIN [AdventureWorks2022].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] dtl ON hdr.SalesOrderID = dtl.SalesOrderID
WHERE dtl.SalesOrderDetailID =  43659


look at query plan and see what is "better"

"why" questions are often a poor fit for Stack Overflow, because the only way to get an authoritative answer is to get the attention of someone who actually works on the product team. But I can say what you're seeing with OR vs UNION has been observed behavior in the community for something like 20 years now, so it's unlikely to change soon.

Fyi union all will perform better again then union unless you specifically need distinct rows

@DaleK - UNION ALL is semantically different to WHERE .. OR ... UNION is correct.

@Alex I wasn't suggesting it was... but many people don't know the difference between union and union all - which is definitely worth knowing for performance reasons.

I only just noticed that you are searching for two different columns SalesOrderID and SalesOrderDetailID - in that case the seeks are needed on two different indexes. Sometimes SQL Server can do an index union plan but the circumstances in which it can do that transformation aren't something I can list (I suspect that the columns would need to come from the same table though)

@Alex i'd say that UNION ALL is more semantically correct than UNION when it comes to WHERE OR because UNION removes duplicates which OR doesn't do. Although, they aren't exact replacement either, it depends on the columns

@siggemannen - but it does! I wrote a test query before posting my initial comment ;)

@Alex see https://dbfiddle.uk/8TfRzEiN

Your Db fiddle is not what OPs queries look like. Try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/CS7w9C2e  . This is getting off topic anyway, as no one actually tried to answer the question.

This answer by Paul White seems to explain it and confirms that SQL cannot come up with the UNION plan with the OR criteria.

This transform only applies to a single table, and does not apply to
attribute-to-attribute comparisons.

